# Why does this CSS3 animation fire only once? How do I fix it?

Tags: jquery, css

**[The fiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/rowbuck/KAKhU/29/)**

HTML:

```
    <div style="background-color: blue">
        <a style="margin-left: 30px;" href="#" class="avatar currentHover2" ><img      class="avatar_img" alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScGVKjsfovuONBaVL4frlyX0KkryNdsigEeCk_EMdowWBj25eN"  style="padding: 10px;">    </a>
        <a style="margin-left: 30px;" href="#" class="avatar currentHover2" ><img class="avatar_img" alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScGVKjsfovuONBaVL4frlyX0KkryNdsigEeCk_EMdowWBj25eN" style= "padding: 10px;">    </a>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(".currentHover2").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('magictime puffIn');
    });
```

CSS file is long and at the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never tell it to remove the class so the effect will run again like so:

```
$(".currentHover2").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('magictime puffIn');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('magictime puffIn');
});
```

Or, rather, originally you add the class and since the class is already there the next time you hover nothing changes.

Comment: Yikes! That was fast.  Thanks, I feel like an ass.

Comment: This stuff is everyday at work.  And I still manage to struggle like this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `class` on `mouseout` after the `hover`.

Try

```
$(".currentHover2").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('magictime puffIn');
}).mouseout(function(){
 $(this).removeClass('magictime puffIn');
});;
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KAKhU/30/)